# classes with two objects

Tags: c++, class, object

this code is working fine for first instance but for second instance it is      not working
input :
poorva
17
26
raju
18
28
for second object i.e raju it is not taking name and roll no and shows some garbage value here is the ideone link  https://ideone.com/uxwMAc

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class student
{
    int roll;
    int age;
    char name[20];

public:
    void getData();
    void showData();

};

void student::getData()
{
    char n[20];
    int a,r;
    cout<<"enter name of student \n";
    gets(name);
    cout<<"enter age of student \n";
    cin>>age;
    cout<<"enter roll no of student \n";
    cin>>roll;

}

void student::showData()
{
    cout<<"details are \n\n";
    cout<<"name is :";
    puts(name);
    cout<<"age is "<<age<<endl;
    cout<<"roll number is "<<roll<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    student poorva ;
    student raju ;
    //for poorva
    poorva.getData();
    poorva.showData();
    //for raju
    raju.getData();
    raju.showData();
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: `gets` is a dangerous function which has been removed in C++14. Please use something else, e.g. `std::string n; /*...*/ cin >> n;` The `gets` function is dangerous because it doesn't perform bounds checking.

Comment: i dont know what ur asking coz u just wrote nonsense in one very long sentence like this without formatting or punctuation or capital letters and did not provide a concrete question for us to answer

Comment: Ok I got it but ,pls expalin it in detail what do you mean by bounds checking ? thanks

Comment: Also, where has this terrible `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` come from? I'm seeing it a lot lately. It's the epitome of laziness. Include only _standard_ headers for standard features.

Comment: _... what do you mean by bounds checking?_ 1. search the interwebs for "bounds checking". 2. come back when you've read and understood enough to ask a sensible question about it.

Comment: This is the same age-old "didn't eat up newlines after input into an `int`" problem. It's asked several times per day. I'm not going bother answering it again, or find a dupe. I'm bored.

Comment: I think `gets` does not consume leading white space, which causes it to read in the `\n` between the inputs `28` and `raju`. Subsequently, `cin>>age` tries to interpret the `raju` input and fails.

Comment: If you're not familiar with bounds checking, then you should ask your professor or teacher. If you don't have one. That is like one of the first things you should learn about (relatively).

Answer (score 1):

`puts` and `gets` are C-derived functions from `<cstdio>`. `cin` and `cout` are C++ streams from `<iostream>`. Don't mix them, they interact badly when they both read from (or write to) the same underlying stream without co-ordinating.

Try using `cin.getline` instead, and remove `puts` entirely. Ideally replace your fixed character array with `std::string` too.

Oh, and don't `#include<bits/stdc++.h>`. That's an implementation detail. Wherever you got the idea that it's reasonable to use this directly, is a bad place to learn C++ and you should stop using it (and maybe name & shame it here).

Your code should probably begin with

```
#include <iostream>
```

instead.

Comment: Lets all shame them together!

Comment: I'll try to keep it constructive :-)

Answer (score -3):

Tey the following

```
Student raju =new Student () ;
```

Though that should have worked. 
Same with pooja

Comment: That won't even _compile_ - this is C++, not Java.